# Nested While Loop not working in python

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax-error, python-3.6

I'm having problems with the second while loop in this.  If I comment out the second while loop everything works fine.  But with it, I get the syntax error listed below.  I want to be able to exit out of the second loop and go back to the first loop.

```
kjv = open('my file path /bible.txt','r').read()

#split each verse into two item list [verse reference, scripture words]:
scriptures_lst = [verse.split('\t') for verse
                    in kjv.split('\n') if verse.split('\t')]

#List of scripture references:
references = [i[0] for i in scriptures_lst]

#Word without scripture references:
word = [i[1] for i in scriptures_lst]

#Books of the bible 
books = [i.rstrip('0123456789: ') for i in references]

#To remove duplicates from list by turning into a set, and then back into a list
bible_books = list(set(books))

#Alphabetize the order of the books:
alph_books = sorted(bible_books)

#Search for verse function
def scripture_search():
    inp = input('verse? ')
    found = next(i for i in scriptures_lst if inp in i)
    return found

continue_inquiry = True
strongs_conc = True

while continue_inquiry == True:
    #USER INPUT
    print("(S)earch, (N)ote, (B)ooks, (K)jv, Strong's \
Exhaustive (C)oncordance, (E)xit")
    request = input('What would you like to do? ')

    if request.upper() == 'SEARCH' or request.upper() == 'S':
        search = scripture_search()
        print(' - '.join(search))

        #WRITE / APPEND VERSES FROM SEARCH TO A TEXT FILE
        #open the file in a+ - append plus mode
        #opens the file for appending to the end of the file (no overwrite) plus read mode
        versesearch_file = open('versesearch_file.txt', 'a+')
        versesearch_file.write(' - '.join(search) + "\n\n")
        versesearch_file.close()

    elif request.upper() == 'NOTE' or request.upper() == 'N':
        note = input('What note would you like to add? ')
        versesearch_file = open('versesearch_file.txt', 'a+')
        versesearch_file.write(note + "\n\n")
        versesearch_file.close()

    #print books of the bible list
    elif request.upper() == 'BOOKS' or request.upper() == 'B':
        print(alph_books)

    #print entire kjv
    elif request.upper() == 'KJV' or request.upper() == 'K':
        print(kjv)

    #start a new while loop for strong's exhaustive concordance
    elif request.upper() == "STRONG'S EXHAUSTIVE CONCORDANCE" or request.upper() == "C":
        while strongs_conc == True:
            print("What would you like to do with Strong's?")
            strongs_inp = input("Get (D)efinition by Strong's Number, (E)xit: "

            if strongs_inp.upper() == 'D':
                print('you selected D')

            elif strongs_inp.upper() == 'EXIT' or strongs_inp.upper() == 'E':
                strongs_conc = False

    #exit from program
    elif request.upper() == 'EXIT' or request.upper() == 'E':
        continue_inquiry = False
```

Error is this:

```
 File "kjv_NAF_backup.py", line 85
    if strongs_inp.upper() == 'D':
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
```

If I comment out this the first loop works fine:

```
# elif request.upper() == "STRONG'S EXHAUSTIVE CONCORDANCE" or request.upper() == "C":
        # while strongs_conc == True:
            # print("What would you like to do with Strong's?")
            # strongs_inp = input("Get (D)efinition by Strong's Number, (E)xit: "

            # if strongs_inp.upper() == 'D':
                # print('you selected D')

            # elif strongs_inp.upper() == 'EXIT' or strongs_inp.upper() == 'E':
                # strongs_conc = False
```

Comment: Missing `)` on the previous line...

Comment: Try putting `elif` closer. i.e. dont leave a line between end of `if` and `elif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax errors on a perfectly valid line of code usually imply unclosed quotes, parenthesis, etc.

In this case you did not close the parenthesis on the previous line: `strongs_inp = input("Get (D)efinition by Strong's Number, (E)xit: "`

Comment: Posting answers to trivial typo errors isn't really recommended; these questions are unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: Didn't see it.  Will request it to be removed.

Comment: I tried to delete it but it will not let me.